# Why my sprintf with usb communication doesn't work very well?

Tags: int, double, avr

I want to send double form uC to PC. For example: in the uC I have double pi=3.1415 after sent it to PC, the console (at the PC) should show 3.1415 . I need to convert double to char, so I used sprintf() to convert it. To be honest I'm not sure that sprintf() is converting double to char[], but it's my only idea. After sent pi to the PC my console shows: ?<00><00>4f<00>˙˙
 . There is my code:

```
#define F_CPU 16000000UL

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void print_char(char letter)
{
    if( bit_is_set(UCSRA, UDRE) )
    {
        _delay_ms(10);
        UDR=letter;
        loop_until_bit_is_set(UCSRA, TXC);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    UBRRL = 103; //9600 16mhz
    UCSRB = (1<<RXEN)|(1<<TXEN)|(1<<RXCIE);
    UCSRC = (1<<URSEL)|(1<<UCSZ1)|(1<<UCSZ0);

    double pi=3.1415;
    char cpi[8];

    sprintf(cpi,"%#.4f", pi);

    while(1)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<8; i++) print_char(cpi[i]);

        UDR=0x0D;
        UDR=0x0A;
        _delay_ms(1000);
    }
}
```

How can I fixed it, or how can I correctly convert double to char[].

Answer (score 1):

`sprintf` and friends are quite costly, in particular the full fledged versions with float support.  To this end, avr-libc provides different versions of `vfprintf`, where the default version does /not/ support `float` and just prints `?` if it sees one.

If you want float support, link with

```
avr-gcc ... -Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_flt
```

see [avr-libc: vfprintf](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdio.html#gaa3b98c0d17b35642c0f3e4649092b9f1).
Moreover, there is support for plain float [conversion functions in stdlib.h](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdlib.html#ga6c140bdd3b9bd740a1490137317caa44).

In the unlikely case you are using avr-gcc with support of 64-bit `double`: avr-libc does not support them, no matter which version of `vfprintf` you are linking.